# Bounded operator on $L^{2}(a,b)$

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory

Let $p\in]1,\infty[$ and consider the mapping

$$ T : L^{2}(-2,2) \to L^{2}(-2,2), \quad (Tf)(x):=xf(x)$$

I want to show that $T$ is bounded, $||Tf||_L \leq T ||f||_L $. So,

$$ ||Tf||_L \leq ||xf(x)||_L = \left( \int_{-2}^{2} |xf(x)|^p dx \right)^{1/p}$$

Can anyone tell me how to proceed from here ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$|(Tf)(x)| \leq |x| |f(x)| \leq 2 |f(x)|$$

for each $x \in (-2,2)$. Now take norms on both sides.

Comment: I was going to suggest Cauchy-Schwarz but this works too.